# Mac OS El Capitan VHost Self-Signed Cert Creation & Use in nginx

Tags: macos, nginx, ssl-certificate, vhosts, nginx-config

I'm trying to generate a `self-signed` `certificate` for development `SSL` use.  This is what I'm using, which creates both the `crt` and the `key`:

```
openssl genrsa -rand -genkey -out pass1.key 2048

openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -key pass1.key -out pass1.crt -sha256
```

The `nginx.conf` block entry for that `vhost` is as follows:

```
listen                  8081 ssl default_server;    
ssl_certificate         /path/to/pass1.crt;
ssl_certificate_key     /path/to/pass1.key;
ssl_ciphers             ALL:!aNULL:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP;
```

`Chrome` isn't happy:

```
NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

I tried importing the `crt` into the `Keychain` inside `System/Certicates` and It threw `Error: -25294`.  At this point I don't know what else to do.  Is this even possible to do?

How can I get an SSL to work on `localhost/vhost` `nginx`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a self-signed certificate without a CA, and it's the CA you need to trust in your keychain. There's an app that can automate all of this for you, [mkcert](https://blog.filippo.io/mkcert-valid-https-certificates-for-localhost/)

Comment: Thanks for the leadership.  I'm getting issues with my local domains, such as `hq.local`: `ERROR: "hq.local," is not a valid hostname or IP`

Comment: Sorry to hear it isn't working for you. Are you getting the same panic referenced in the above issue? mkcert works well for me on Mojave, and I don't have any El Cap machines to test with.

Comment: I couldn't get `mkcert` to work, but tweaking `Chrome` got me past the challenge.  It's documented that the library wouldn't work if not `https` but it's working enough.